# Django serializer not raising exception over model constraints

Tags: django

I have this dummy model

```
from django.db import models
class ChertModel(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(gettext_lazy('username'), max_length=150, unique=True)
    o2 = models.CharField(gettext_lazy('username2'), max_length=150,editable=False, default='lllss')
```

and with serializer

```
class ChertSer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ChertModel
        fields = ['username','o2']
```

note I have an instance with `username='sd'` and `o2='434as'`

so when in the view I want to update the `o2` fields which is supposedly `editable=False` it doesnt update it which is ok but the problem is that it doesnt raise exception over model constraints.

note I have checked this configuration with `editable=True` and the serializer applies changes thus there is no problem with serializer.

```
class ChertView(views.APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        lt1=ChertModel.objects.get(username='sd')
        print('1',lt1.o2)
        ser=ChertSer(instance=lt1, data={'username':'sd','o2':'newo2'}, partial=True)
        print(ser.is_valid())
        ser.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        ser.save()
        lt1=ChertModel.objects.get(username='sd')
        print('2',lt1.o2)
```

since it shows the serializer.is_valid `True` and wont raise exception would make problem of changes of user not applied to model instance without acknowledging it to user.

so my question is how to detect the times the updating object is not applied due to model constraints?

of course I can manually detect it by checking `ser.data=={'username':'sd','o2':'newo2'}` but `ser.data` is only can be achieved after saving the instance and not before it. besides this way doesnt specify the constraint which is not applied. the equivalent is to manually check for all attributes which is not agreeable when we are using a framework.

so is there any more formal or common way to automatically detect constraints not being applied before saving the instance?

Answer (score 0):

[If False, the field will not be displayed in the admin or any other ModelForm. They are also skipped during model validation. Default is True.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#editable)

The validation on perticuler field is skipped by default, what you can do is overwrite the `validation` function in serializer and raise exception from their.

Comment: I know that and it makes no difference. this means I have to manually check all the constraints which is not desirable. btw I can already `raise serializers.ValidationError` that here in views

Comment: you won't have to check all constraints, just check the o2 one, and that's it.

Comment: I am not talking about this dummy example.

Answer (score 0):

When `editable=False` is specified. The field won't be shown in admin or any other ModelForms, they are also skipped during validation.

You can specify `read_only_fields` at the serializer level.

```
class ChertSer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ChertModel
        fields = ['username','o2']
        read_only_fields = ('o2',)
```

If there are multiple serializers for this model and you dont want to dupilicate adding these. You can define read only fields at an AbstractSerializer and inherit it over serializer.